# Microsoft Office Small Business Edition - Medialess license - Download software

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, license-key

My client has a media-less license for Office 2007
He has since re-formatted his hard drive, and no longer has the software.

He has his certificate, and license key..

Where can we download it, to apply the license key to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Microsoft, they can point you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 As Drake says,one call will solve this.  Have always found it quick and relatively painless

Answer (score 1):

The DVD case should have the link in it - http://www.microsoft.com/office/backup/ was the one my dad had on his, though it might vary based off country